# is fetch() data from API and get() data from API the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an assignment to: use the method GET to fetch api info from http://api.example.com/. I'm also told to only use: Javascript/Reactjs

However, everywhere I search, I can only fetch the data. Are these two the same thing? Or am I looking at the wrong tutorials?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json,
        })
      });
  }

  render() {

    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
              <li key={item.uid}>
                Name: {item.name} | Email:{item.email}
              </li>
            ))};
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: fetch() is the tool to make the requests....they can be GET, POST, PUT, DELETE , HEAD, PATCH etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

they are interchangeable, as a technical jargon from the field, "get data from api" and "fetch data from the api" means the same thing.

in javascript, nowadays, we use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to interact with an api, using [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) like `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, `DELETE`.

unfortunately i don't know a page or repository listing these jargons

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is a javascript API used for making XHR requests across the web (normally for interacting with an API).

```
let promise = fetch(url, {
  method: "GET", // POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  headers: {
    // the content type header value is usually auto-set
    // depending on the request body
    "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: undefined // string, FormData, Blob, BufferSource, or URLSearchParams
  referrer: "about:client", // or "" to send no Referer header,
  // or an url from the current origin
  referrerPolicy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade", // no-referrer, origin, same-origin...
  mode: "cors", // same-origin, no-cors
  credentials: "same-origin", // omit, include
  cache: "default", // no-store, reload, no-cache, force-cache, or only-if-cached
  redirect: "follow", // manual, error
  integrity: "", // a hash, like "sha256-abcdef1234567890"
  keepalive: false, // true
  signal: undefined, // AbortController to abort request
  window: window // null
});
```

But GET is an HTTP verb. The primary or most-commonly-used HTTP verbs (or methods, as they are properly called) are POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE. These correspond to create, read, update, and delete (or CRUD) operations, respectively.

To understand more about these methods read  **Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures** by Dr Roy Fielding or popularly know as roy fielding paper which describes about the RESTful nature of the web and the use of these HTTP verbs. [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)